# Scala Iterator Filter Abstract Method

Tags: scala, iterator

I'm currently trying to get to know Scala (2.10.2) iterators and their behaviour. I'm interested in using methods such as `filter` and `map`, which according to various places on the internet, are implemented lazily, which is helpful.

However, when I implement the Iterator[T] interface, calling `filter` on it throws a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`. Can anyone throw some light on why?

An example:

```
class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]
{ 
    private var i = 0

    def hasNext : Boolean = i < 10

    def next() : Int =
    { 
        val ret = i
        i += 1
        ret
    }
}
```

and then in the console:

```
scala> new SillyIterator
res20: SillyIterator = SillyIterator@4659d97

scala> res20.filter( _ > 3 )
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: SillyIterator.filter(Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;
    ...
```

EDIT:

This isn't caused by paste mode issues. If I define the whole class as a one-liner, it still fails:

```
scala> class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]{ private var i = 0; def hasNext : Boolean = i < 10; def next() : Int = { val ret = i; i += 1; ret } }
defined class SillyIterator

scala> val s = new SillyIterator
s: SillyIterator = SillyIterator@5bf1effb

scala> s.next
res0: Int = 0

scala> s.filter( _ < 3 )
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: SillyIterator.filter(Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;
    at .<init>(<console>:13)
    ...
```

Comment: Your code works on REPL with Scala 2.10.1

Comment: Paste mode is the solution, but getting an `AbstractMethodError` in the REPL is a bug. How did you compile that class? Can you show the full REPL session?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine in IDE, but there may be some problems in worksheet and REPL.

To avoid those problems, just move the bracket to the first line. Like this:

```
class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]{
  private var i = 0

  def hasNext : Boolean = i < 10

  def next() : Int = {
    val ret = i
    i += 1
    ret
  }
}
```

In your case, you had the definition of the class SillyIterator

```
class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]
```

followed by the block of code in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in the REPL and you don't need to move up the curly bracket (although I personally find that syntax irritating), what you need to do is enter in paste mode using `:pa`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]
{ 
    private var i = 0

    def hasNext : Boolean = i < 10

    def next() : Int =
    { 
        val ret = i
        i += 1
        ret
    }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class SillyIterator

scala> new SillyIterator
res15: SillyIterator = non-empty iterator

scala> res15.filter( _ > 3 )
res16: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res15.filter( _ > 3 ).toList
res17: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

If you don't use the paste mode the new line will matter in the REPL, this is what you get if you don't use it (or move on the upper line the curly bracket):

```
scala> class SillyIterator extends Iterator[Int]
<console>:7: error: class SillyIterator needs to be abstract, since:
it has 2 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from class SillyIterator, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
...
```